# ExecuteListener extract ExecuteContext table, columns and row values

Tags: jooq

I'm using jOOQ `ExecuteListener` SPI to perform external API call as a pre-commit hook. My goal is to invoke a network call with the some of the inserted values (the logic will be written based on each table), and if that fails, the transaction should rollback.

Here's what I tried first:

Using `ExecuteContext` instance, I could access the query, SQL statement, params. However, I couldn't know what the table name is without having to parse the string SQL statement.

```java
public class WriteListener implements ExecuteListener {

  @Override
  public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.type() == ExecuteType.WRITE) {
      // extract table, rows and their values
      final org.jooq.Query query = ctx.query(); // tried to cast to InsertQuery too
      final org.jooq.Record record = ctx.record(); // can't access the values
      // etc..
    }
    ExecuteListener.super.end(ctx);
  }
}
```

The other option was to try using an experimental API `QOM`:

```java
public class WriteListener implements ExecuteListener {

  @Override
  public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.query() instanceof QOM.Insert insert) {
      final Table table = insert.$into();
      final var cols = insert.$columns();
      final var rows = insert.$values();
      // can't extract row values!
    }
    ExecuteListener.super.end(ctx);
  }
}
```

I was able to read the table, the columns and the fields. However, can't extract values without reflection.

The ultimate goal is to get cast a record to one of the codegen record types, where I could get storngly-typed objects, and that would have the values populated. I'm not sure if that's possible today tho. Ideally, looking for the following code:

```java
public class WriteListener implements ExecuteListener {

  @Override
  public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.type() == ExecuteType.WRITE) {
      // NOTE: THIS DOES NOT WORK, IT'S AN IDEA ONLY.
      if (ctx.record() instanceof MyTableRowRecord record) {
        final DateTime createdAt = record.CREATED_AT;
        // invoke an external API call with the table name, and the created at value.
      }
    }
    ExecuteListener.super.end(ctx);
  }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm on the Community Edition, but if that is an API on another tier i'm willing to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was able to read the table, the columns and the fields. However, can't extract values without reflection.

Why do you need reflection to access fields / values? [`QOM.Insert.$values()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/QOM.Insert.html#$values()) returns a list of [`Row`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Row.html) types, which offers [`Row.$fields()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Row.html#$fields()) and each [`Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html) can be a [`Param`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Param.html) (or something else, of course). So:

```java
for (Row row : insert.$values()) {
    for (Field<?> field : row.$fields()) {
        if (field instanceof Param<?> param) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

> The ultimate goal is to get cast a record to one of the codegen record types, where I could get storngly-typed objects, and that would have the values populated.

The `ExecuteListener` SPI is not aware of any "strongly typed objects" such as `UpdatableRecord` types. Assuming that you originally called something like this:

```java
MyTableRowRecord record = ...
record.insert();
```

This will trigger the `RecordListener` SPI prior to generating an `INSERT` statement, whose execution then triggers the `ExecuteListener` SPI. But again, the latter is unaware of the records, whereas the former is invoked only for `UpdatableRecord` operations.

> It's worth mentioning that I'm on the Community Edition, but if that is an API on another tier i'm willing to upgrade.

From what I can tell in your question, an upgrade isn't strictly necessary. The `QOM` API itself might suffice. There are some useful utilities in the commercial editions, such as [`QOM` traversal](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-traversal/) and [replacement](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-replacement/), for example.

Comment: interesting! I didn't realise that `Param` extends `Field`, that helps a lot. The only missing piece of the puzzle now is getting the field name that corresponds to a value. I tried to use `param.getValue()`, I get `the value`, and when I use `param.getName()`, I get `"the value"`. Is this expected? (I can submit an MCVE) If not, is it safe to assume that `$fields()` sorting order will match the `$columns()` sorting order?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the arity must match, in principle, the [`Insert.$columns()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/QOM.Insert.html#$columns()) and `Insert.$values()` are independent entities. So, you'll have to remember column indexes from `Insert.$columns()` and count your way through the `Row.$fields()` to get a hold of field names.